# logic:messagesPresent property attribute; What is the c:if equivalent?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl, struts

Currently in my JSP I have the following `logic` tag:

```
                <logic:messagesPresent property="eve">
                    <span class="form-error">
                </logic:messagesPresent>
```

I'm trying to replace this `logic:messagesPresent` tag with a `c:if` tag instead, but I'm not sure how to handle the `property="eve"` with `c:if`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the property in test attribute:

You can do it as below:

```
 <c:if test = "${not empty eve}">
        <span class="form-error">
 </c:if>
```